# VSCode: IntelliSense from files loaded with a wrapped require()

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, alias, intellisense, require

Is there any way to tell VSCode that a function is just a wrapper around `require(...)` or it is an alias for it?

I looked into the documentation for writing extensions and I found the `CompletionItemProvider` and some others, but I would have to parse the referenced files myself, so I would need to reinvent the wheel... I would only like to tell VSCode somehow the file that is referenced by this function.

**Edit:**
Simple example:

```
// main.js
const foo = importModule("foo.js");
```

```
// foo.js
module.exports = {
    bar: "asdf",
    baz(num) {
        return num * 2;
    }
};
```

I would like to work `importModule()` like `require()` does with IntelliSense. The thing is, I can't use `require()` as this code runs in an environment, where `importModule()` is used instead of `require()`.

Comment: You may be able to use jsdoc for this. Can you please provide a short, simple code example of what you are trying to do

Comment: Not an answer but I've opened https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33333 for one approach using `/** @type {import('./foo')} */` that should work but doesn't currently